# Express-validator throwing error with valid fields

Tags: javascript, html, express, sequelize.js, express-validator

I'm relatively new to node and express, and have come across a problem I can't seem to solve.

So I came across with the problem trying to validate a create product form, that when I introduce correct values into the fields express-validator throws error.

This is my routes code:

```
router.post('/create', [
    check('name').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage("Invalid Value"),
    check('description').isLength({ min: 20 }).withMessage("Invalid Value")
] , upload.any() , productosController.guardarCreado);
```

This is my productosController code:

```
    guardarCreado: (req, res, next) => {
        let errors = validationResult(req);
        if(errors.isEmpty()){ 
        db.Product.create({
            name: req.body.nombre,
            description: req.body.descripcion,
            size: req.body.talle,
            price: req.body.precio,
            category_id: 2,
            img_url: req.files[0].filename
        })
        res.redirect('/productos');
    }else{
        db.Category.findAll()
        .then(function(categorias){
            return res.render('crearProductos', { categorias: categorias, errors: errors.errors });
            })
        }
    }
```

And my form code is from Bootstrap and the names of the form fields are the same as the names on the 'check' from my routes code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <label for="validationDefault03">Nombre del Producto</label>
                  <input name="name" id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ej: Remera River Plate"  >
                </div>
```

```
 <div class="col-12">
                  <label for="description" class="form-label">Descipción:</label><br>
                  <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-input"></textarea>
              </div>
```

Error display on the the form via EJS:

```
        <% if (typeof errors != 'undefined') { %>
            <p style= "color: red">ERROR</p>
            </div>
                <ul>
                    <% for(let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) { %>
                        <li>
                            <%= errors[i].msg %>
                        </li>
                        <% } %>
                </ul>
            <% } %>
```

Comment: may you add the error output which you get

Comment: I dont really get an error, just when I try to create a product via the form i always get the messages from express validator "Invalid Value" with the withMessage() function, even though the values are correct. I added the ejs code that displays the errors.

Comment: I am getting this error too, pls how do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

got the solution after working for hour on error:

Solution - Replace the query keyword with body:
`const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator')`
instead of
`const { query, validationResult } = require('express-validator')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).